# What PHP function will allow me to print $str="<Source of the rule. E.g. stakeholder>"?

Tags: php, html, html-entities, strip-tags

I am trying to implement the following code.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>  
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>  
<?php
$str="<Source of the rule. E.g. stakeholder>";
echo $str;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

But I am not getting my string as an output on the screen using echo command.
I have also used the `strip_tags` function but did not work.
Can anybody help me to print the exact string by using PHP. The output is blank screen. Nothing is printing on the screen.

Comment: Have you tried `echo $str` after the variable is set?

Comment: yes sir i have also used echo $str;

Comment: You've tagged this with `html-entities`, which I'm pretty sure is the function you're looking for. Have you tried that?

Comment: sir i also used htmlentities($str). Still not working.

Comment: Please show the rendered output of your code.  Just saying "not working" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Does that tag name `Source of the rule. E.g. stakeholder` have any further meaning?

Comment: @NicoHaase Even if it doesn't, OP should be able to print it as a valid string

Answer (score 3):

Use a combination of `htmlentities` and `html_entity_decode`

```
$str='<Source of the rule. E.g. stakeholder>';
echo htmlentities(html_entity_decode($str));
```

Comment: Thanks sir @anurag srivastava. Your solution perfectly worked.